# SQL Join Tables error due to strange characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Everyone,

I have a new error for me in SQL (Windows 2016) I can not figure out. I am trying to combine to SQL tables with INNER Join. But one table has an error or strange character set in messing up the Inner join. see below

Table with error

```
[ADM].[dbo].[weastatus_with_ver]
```

[image]

You can see in the columns (RFC, VER) have this strange numbering. It should be blank or complete numbers like the rest.

Now when I do my SQL query to join on this above table: like below

```
SELECT 
    wt.WEA
    , wt.RFC        
    , fm.VER
    , fm.POS
    , fm.FM
    , fm.EN
    , fm.VERF
    , fm.KLASS
    , fm.BRAKE
    , fm.RESET
    , fm.POTENTIAL_FE      
FROM  
    [ADM].[dbo].[paradb_fm] AS fm
INNER JOIN  
    [ADM].[dbo].[weastatus_with_ver] AS wt ON fm.VER = wt.VER
WHERE 
    wt.WEA = 81254
    AND fm.VER = 222
```

The error I am getting is:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0 (' to data type int.

I have tried Inner join, left, right. do a union of two tables, just cant get it same error. I know I must be missing something here any help would be great.

Is there a way to exclude the strange characters and complete the join?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, is there a reason you tagged the [tag:r] programming language and the [tag:sqlite] (not sqlserver) software library?

Comment: What are the respective `data_type`s for the two joining columns? `select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where (table_name='paradb_fm' and column_name='VER') or (table_name='weastatus_with_ver' and column_name='VER')` (or something like that).

Comment: My guess is that you imported two datasets (from excel or csv or something), and gauging from your *picture* of data, one of them has a malformed `VER` (likely `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` or such), whereas the other is all correct (and therefore interpreted to be `INT`).

Comment: r2evans First, fixed the tags, next the tables are in my company's sql server. I can query each table separate with no issues, but when I combine the two is where i get the error.

Comment: `JOIN` is *the operation* you ask the DBMS to do with **your** data, `0(0)` is *the data* you want to apply this operation on. DBMS knows completely nothing about the semantics and meaning of **your** data and just trust you. So no one can know how do you want to interpret this data, that should be a number, not this nonsense. Use appropriate datatypes in your design: `int` for integer numbers, `decimal` for precise numbers with decimal fractions, `date` for dates etc.

Comment: You want to join string with integer, so no surprise DBMS cannot compare them as numbers (can you?). Convert your `INT` column to `VARCHAR` with [`cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) and do joins, unions, whatever.

Comment: Thanks will give it a go and let you know

Comment: Perhaps as simple as `ON cast(fm.VER as nchar(5)) = wt.VER` (or whatever string length is appropriate for your data). Ultimately, the query I suggested earlier will inform this method and the length of `cast`-length; do too little, you'll see problems and/or over-eager joins; do too much, and it'll still work but will be slightly less efficient. So err on the high-side if in doubt.

Comment: @r2evans You beat me to it but thanks I did just that and it worked.

Comment: @astentx Thanks also. It has been long day.

Comment: imho, BB.squared, this looks to be a data-corruption in the import process. Over to you, but if you have `VER` columns in two tables that are supposed to be the same type, this suggests somebody was inattentive when importing data. It's not hard to fix (and should be fixed so that you don't have to `ON cast(...)=...` every single time), but as is generally the case with problems like this: we can find a solution that helps you with this query, but the much better solution is to *also* (or *instead*) fix the importing process so that this does not happen again. Glad it worked.

Comment: @r2evans I thought the same and will be having that talk with Germany on Monday.

Comment: @astentx, it was your suggestion that worked, I think you should post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to avoid implicit conversion and to use *explicit* conversion.

It is unclear in your question what columns have what types, but the idea for the `JOIN` is to make the types the same.  You can convert a string to an int:

```
fm.VER = TRY_CONVERT(int, wt.VER)
```

Or and int to a string:

```
fm.VER = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), wt.VER)
```

Of course, the real fix is that two columns named `VER` should have the same type, so `JOIN`s work.  Type conversion also can have a really bad impact on performance.

You have potentially a similar issue in the `WHERE` clause.  For instance, if `fm.VER` is a string, then:

```
fm.VER = 222
```

attempts to convert `fm.VER` to a number.  Don't mix types in the `WHERE` clause either.